# calculating the max using math import

Tags: math, max

im starter in java so i would be happy if somebody answer my question in a simple way.
im trying to calculate max by using max import :s but it gives me error :(

here is the script :

```
package Calc;

import java.lang.Math.*;

public class Calculator {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int n1,n2;
        String s="10 , 20";
        //converting strings to integers
        String s1=s.substring(3,s.length());
        String [] s2=s1.split(",");
        n1=Integer.parseInt(s2[0]);
        n2=Integer.parseInt(s2[1]);

        //max
        int maxstock = Math.max(n1 , n2);
        System.out.println(maxstock);

    }
}
```

here is the error intellij idea gives :

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
>       at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:48)
>       at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:468)
>       at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:497)
>       at Calc.Calculator.main(Calculator.java:16)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>       at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)

Process finished with exit code 1

(i converted string to integer instead of using it directly cause this is a class work and it must be like that)

Answer (score 0):

```
String s1=s.substring(3,s.length());
```

that gives you `s1` as `", 20"`.

```
String [] s2=s1.split(",");
```

splits `s1` at the comma, you get `s2[0] = ""` and `s2[1] = " 20"`.

```
n1=Integer.parseInt(s2[0]);
```

causes

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""

because an empty string cannot be parsed as an `int`.

Did you perhaps intend

```
String [] s2=s.split(",");
```

to split the entire string `"10 , 20"`?

But then you would still get a `NumberFormatException`, because `Integer.parseInt` doesn't accept any whitespace in the string it tries to parse.